# limit the length of a line in threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am creating a line in threejs, whose vertices are tied to a number of random particles which float around in space randomly, essentially "connecting the dots." What I'd like to do is limit the length of that line though, if it goes above a certain distance. If I inspect the properties of the line, I can see, in addition to line.geometry.vertices - a property for line.geometry.lineDistances, but its length is 0. Can this feature be used in threejs? Or is there another way to limit the length of the line?

Comment: Use Sphere .setFromPoints then multiply the radius of the bounding sphere by 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
line.geometry.boundingSphere.radius * 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your logic correctly you have points that float randomly in space independently.  Then you have a line that is drawn between the points, this line is dependent on the two points.  Instead of trying to control the size of the line I believe you should try to control the max distance between the points.

Comment: No - I want the points to be able to travel far, but if they are too far from each other, I want the line to essentially redraw itself only between points within the allowable distance. The problem is, I don't want to get rid of these vertices permanently (if the particle passes back into range, I want the line to redraw itself to this point).

Comment: Then why not only draw the line to points within a certain delta of the point of interest?

Comment: to optimize performance, the line is drawn when threejs initializes. The points animate, and the line follows these points. If I want to draw them to within a certain delta, this means I would have to constantly monitor the distance of the points from each other, and splice / add vertices based on their distance between each other. I've figured out a way to do this, but one - it's processor intensive, and two, I'd rather not change the vertices of the line itself, but instead just hide / show segments.